# Problemas de ScrollTriger en responsive

Tags: javascript, scroll

Hola estoy haciendo unas pruebas simples con ScrollTrigger de https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger

funciona muy bien pero en responsive no hace nada de los efectos, he probado y releido pero no encuentro la solución, seguro que algo nimio se me escapa pero me esta empezando a molestar jajajaja, ¿Alguien ha tenido este problema y lo ha solventado? ¿alguien puede ayudarme?
este es el código :

```js
 const tl = gsap.timeline({
            scrollTrigger: {
              trigger: ".trigger",
              start: "top top",
              end: "+=1000",
              scrub: 1,
              pin: true,
              markers: true
            }
          });
          tl.to(".box", {yPercent: 350, duration: 1})
          tl.to(".box", {rotation: 360, duration: 3})
          tl.to(".box", {xPercent: 350, duration: 1})
```

```css
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika+Negative:300,400&display=swap');

        body {
            font-family: "Signika Negative", sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
            height: 300vh;
        }

        .trigger {
            position: absolute;
            top: 75vh;
            left: 0;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 80vh;
            background-color: lightgray;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .box {
            background-color: black;
            width: 10vw;
            height: 10vw;
        }
```

```html
<h1>Scroll down</h1>

    <div class="trigger">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Será por el padding fijo que le estás dando a la clase _trigger_? (está en px). Y no es que no se dan los efectos, ¡no se ven!

Comment: Yo veo que funciona igual en cualquier resolución de pantalla :S